# Calculate count of up and down vote plugin

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Currently I have a jQuery upvote Plugin in my project. So, with every I click upvote it saves the value in the db as a true, with every vote taken back it save the value as false in the database and saves the value in the other column as 0. All I was trying to do is to count the total number of votes just like stack overflow does. Even now I am so confuse to on how to solve this issue. I end up making this code in php which is also make my whole program slow:

```
$sample1 = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * from Ratings WHERE TopicID = :current");
$sample1->bindParam(':current', $id);
$sample1->execute();
$RES1 = $sample1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
$upVote = 0;

foreach ($RES1 as $mk){
     if(($mk['Upvote'] === 'true') && ($mk['Downvote'] ==='false')){
             $upVote++;
                                    }
     else if(( $mk['Upvote'] ==='false') && ($mk['Downvote'] === 'true')){
             $upVote--;
                                }
     else if(($mk['Upvote'] === 'false') && ($mk['Downvote'] === 'false')){
            $upVote--;
                                }
     else if(($mk['Downvote'] === 'false')){
             $upVote++;
                                }
     else if(($mk['Downvote'] === 'true') && ($mk['Upvote'] ==='0') || ($mk['Upvote'] === 'false')){
             $upVote--;
     }

 }
```

My table structure :
[image: table]

For the above example my counter should be be 0

Comment: What datatypes are those two columns? Why not just get the counts using a simple SQL query?

Comment: Please edit your question and show and example of the expected result you are looking for.

Comment: @SloanThrasher those are varchar

Comment: @SloanThrasher Just like stack over flow. When you up vote counter increment by 1. When you undo your upvote counter decrease to 0, when you downvote counter decrease to -1, when you upvote from downvote counter increment to 1

Comment: See my answer below. But with the idea of simplifying the logic, would you get a correct count of upvotes/downvotes by counting the number of trues?

Comment: For the example data in your question, what would be the correct score? Please edit your question to show the answer. -2?

Comment: I think it should be 0 not -2

Comment: true in DownVote means -1,then true in upvote means 1,the false in upvote means the user have undo his vote and the counter is 0 again like that..

Comment: Does 0 in a column mean ignore the other column? Also, you said in your question that if you rescind a vote, it stores false in that column, and zero in the other, yet several have true and zero. Why is that?

Comment: @SloanThrasher Ok, so I am using this jquery plugin https://github.com/janosgyerik/jquery-upvote#options-and-their-default-values to implement the upvote functionality in my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think with a little more study, the conditions you show to decide up or down count could be simplified quite a bit. But, here's a SQL statement that implements your conditions:

```
SELECT
    SUM(
        IF(Upvote='true' AND Downvote='false',1,
            IF(upvote='false' AND Downvote='true',-1,
                IF(Upvote='false' AND Downvote='false',-1,
                    IF(Downvote='false',1,
                        IF(Downvote='true' AND (Upvote='0' OR Upvote=false),-1,0)
                    )
                )
            )
        )) as `votes`
FROM Ratings
WHERE TopicD = :current
```

If only 'true' values count, this might do the trick:

```
SELECT
    SUM(IF(Upvote='true',1,0)) - SUM(IF(Downvote='true',1,0)) as `votes`
FROM Ratings
WHERE TopicD = :current
```